# SPGroupCollection with missing groups

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to get one user group in SP 2010. I currently have five groups but SPGroupCollection only contains two when i read the groups with `oSPWeb.Groups`. Anyone know if there is any security or other reason for this?

Code:

```
 using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(_serverUrl))
            {

                using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                {

                                SPGroup spGroup = oSPWeb.Groups["AIT Owners"];

                    }   

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a security reason. The [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.groups.aspx) property will only return groups that have assigned permissions within the website, while the [SiteGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitegroups) property returns all groups within the site collection.

For more information, there are a [number of blog articles](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&q=spweb%20%22groups%22%20%22sitegroups%22%20difference%20OR%20vs) that cover the difference.